# AngularJS: pass perameter to $location.path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I suspect what I'm trying to do is very simple, I'm new to Angular so some obvious practices sort of go over my head. I'm having trouble accessing the show view (sorry, I'm coming to angular from Rails, so I still think in those terms a little bit) for my Acts resource. The view renders fine, but it isn't displaying the data I would like. I suspect the template isn't receiving the $scope.act variable I'm defining in the controller. When I use console.log in the controller, I can see that the variable contains all the data I want to use. I assume I have to do something to pass the variable as a parameter to the template, but I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Here's my code:

*app.js*

```
$(document).on('page:load', function() {
    return $('[ng-app]').each(function() {
        var module;
        module = $(this).attr('ng-app');
        return angular.bootstrap(this, [module]);
    });
});

var snowball_effect = angular.module('snowball_effect', [
    'templates', 
    'ngRoute', 
    'ngResource',
    'controllers'
]);

snowball_effect.config([
    '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        return $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: "static_pages/templates/index.html",
            controller: 'StaticPagesController'
        })
        .when('/acts/index', {
            templateUrl: "acts/templates/index.html",
            controller: 'ActsController'
        })
        .when('/acts/:id', {
            templateUrl: "acts/templates/show.html",
            controller: 'ActsController'
        });
    }
]);

var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
```

*ActsController.js*

```
controllers = angular.module('controllers');

controllers.controller('ActsController', [
    '$scope', 
    '$routeParams', 
    '$location', 
    '$resource', 
    function($scope,$routeParams,$location,$resource) {

        var Act = $resource('/acts/:actId', {
            actId: "@id",
            format: 'json'
        },  {
            'create': {
                method: 'POST'
            }
        });

        $scope.acts = Act.query();

        $scope.addAct = function() {
            act = Act.save($scope.newAct, function() {
                $scope.acts.push(act);
                $scope.newAct = '';
            });
        }

        $scope.deleteAct = function(act) {
            Act.delete(act);
            $scope.acts.splice($scope.acts.indexOf(act), 1);
        }

        $scope.linkToShowAct = function(act) {
            $scope.act = act;
            console.log($scope.act);
            $location.path('acts/' + act.id);
        }
}]);
```

*show.html*

```
<div class="acts-show">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="ActsController">
        <div class="body">

            <h1>
                {{act.name}}
            </h1>

            <p class="act-show-description">
                {{act.description}}
            </p>

            <p class="act-show-inspires">
                <strong>Inspires:</strong>
                {{act.inspires}}
            </p>

            <a href="#/">Edit</a>
            <a href="#/">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*index.html*

```
<div class="actions_body">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Listing Actions</h2>

    <div ng-controller="ActsController" class="body">
      <table class="row">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 active">
              <label>Name</label>
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-4">Description</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Inspires</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="col-md-2">Modify</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="act in acts">
          <td class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-2"><a href="" ng-click="linkToShowAct(act)">{{act.name}}</a></td>
          <td class="col-md-4">{{act.description}}</td>
          <td class="col-md-2">{{act.inspires}}</td>
          <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
          <td><button ng-click="deleteAct(act)">Delete</a></button>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <br>

      <button ng-click="newActShow=true">New Action</button>
      <button ng-click="newActShow=false">Hide</button>

      <div ng-show="newActShow" id="newAct">
        <div class="row">
          <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="addAct()">
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
              <label for="newActname">Name</label>
              <input type="text" ng-model="newAct.name" id="newActname" placeholder="Name" class="form-control col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
              <label for="newActdescription">Description</label>
              <input type="textarea" ng-model="newAct.description" id="newActdescription" placeholder="Description" class="form-control col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
              <label for="newActinspires">Inspires</label>
              <input type="number" ng-model="newAct.inspires" id="newActinspires" placeholder="Inspires" class="form-control col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="+" class="btn btn-success">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect there can be some console output maybe? In that case can you paste here the error?

Comment: For one, I think you shold get rid of `ng-controller="ActsController"` because you're defining your controller already in the route. Other than that, you show.html looks good. Do you have any errors in the console when you run the page?

Comment: I got rid of ng-controller. There's no error message. That's why I think the app just doesn't know what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think that your code is way overcomplicated, I mean that you can simply create one module and one controller. Also you can use ng-app="yourmodule" instead of the fancy $(document) code...

Comment: The $(document) code makes it work with turbolinks on rails.

Comment: can you please create a working jsfiddle to reproduce the error?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd create a jsfiddle, as the problem is occurring when I route to the show template, and jsfiddle only allows you to use one html page.

Answer (score 0):

try `$locationChangeStart` in order to make sure your value is set to the scope variable before the state actually changes and the route happens, even if you put the `$location.path('acts/' + act.id);` before setting the variable, there is no guarantee that the value will be set before the state change (the actual routing).
 I would prefer (a more safe value setting method) using a promise for example ..

Comment: I'm trying to find a good explanation of how $locationChangeStart works. How would this look?

Comment: your variable is left in the first instance of ActsControllers, for instance try to put  :  '$rootScope.act = act;' instead of  '$scope.act = act;'  if works then we find a way to pass the scope / data to the another view , maybe you will be changing to "stateProvider" then